# Why I'm getting reverse results

Tags: javascript, html, json

I don't know what's wrong with my code, it's reversing the result but in the console everything is fine where I'm getting the correct result.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "currentUser": {
      "image": {
        "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
        "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
      },
      "username": "juliusomo"
    },
    "comments": [
      {
        "user": {
          "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png"
          },
          "username": "amyrobson"
        }
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png"
          },
          "username": "maxblagun"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

And my JavaScript:

```
fetch("test.json")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => showinfo(data));

let count = -1;
function showinfo(data) {
  for (const l in data) {
    count++
    const users = `
    <div>
      <p>${data.comments[count].user.username}</p>
      <img src='${data.comments[count].user.image.png}' alt='not found'/>
    </div>
    `
    document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",users);
    console.log(data.comments[count].user.username);
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on and how can I fix it

Comment: what "results" are in the console? what "results" are "reverse"? inserting "afterbegin" in a loop will result in the insertions in reverse order to what you may expect

Comment: if you want the order you need, build up a string in the loop and add it ONCE after the loop - more performant as a bonus

Comment: To be honest, your `for` loop is suspect, and only works because you happen to have two top level properties (`currentUser` and `comments`) and two comments - if there were only one comment, you'd get an error, if there were more than one comment, your code would only show the first 2

Comment: in the console i am getting 'amyrobson'  first and 'maxblagun' after that but  when i am adding to the body then it gets reversed 'maxblagun' comes first and 'amyrobson' after that

Comment: `afterbegin` inserts the content at the beginning of the body. If you do this repeatedly what was previously inserted will keep getting pushed "down"

Comment: yes, I thought I explained that, @VivekRai - but the comment above should nail it home

Answer (score 2):

Because afterbegin inserts at the top of body, the next iteration will insert BEFORE the previous

I'd recommend the following - build up the string for each iteration, then insert ONCE

```js
const data = {
  "currentUser": {
    "image": {
      "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
      "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
    },
    "username": "juliusomo"
  },
  "comments": [{
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png"
        },
        "username": "maxblagun"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png"
        },
        "username": "wont show"
      }
    }
  ]
};

let count = -1;
let users ='';
function showinfo(data) {
  for (const l in data) {
    count++
    users += `
    <div>
      <p>${data.comments[count].user.username}</p>
      <img src='${data.comments[count].user.image.png}' alt='not found'/>
    </div>
    `
    console.log(data.comments[count].user.username);
  }
  document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", users);
}
showinfo(data);
```

However, you'll notice I added a third comment which doesn't show - this is because your `for` loop is flawed - it only seems to work because you happen to have two comments and two top level properties in `data`

Here's a fix

```js
const data = {
  "currentUser": {
    "image": {
      "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
      "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
    },
    "username": "juliusomo"
  },
  "comments": [{
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png"
        },
        "username": "maxblagun"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-willshow.png"
        },
        "username": "will show"
      }
    }
  ]
};

function showinfo(data) {
  let users = data.comments.map(({user}) => `<div>
      <p>${user.username}</p>
      <img src='${user.image.png}' alt='not found'/>
    </div>`).join('')
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", users);
}
showinfo(data);
```

Also note the use of `document.body` rather than the unnecessarily overcomplicated `document.querySelector("body")`